# How to read values from properties file in batch programming

Tags: batch-file, properties

I have a properties file that contain values in the format of

```js
variable_one = value_one
variable_two = value_two
.
.
.
.



. and so on
```

with file name as testing.properties which is in the same directory of batch script
No i am building a batch file that should run in such a way that double clicking it has to read values into some variables and display it on screen

```js
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" "variable_one", "variable_two" IN (testing.properties) DO (
 IF "variable_one"=="variable_one" set local_variable_one=%%B
  IF "variable_two"=="variable_two" set local_variable_two=%%C
 )
 
echo "%local_variable%"

pause
```

Comment: Do you want to read all the properties and display their values, or read certain properties and display their values?

Comment: The __FOR__ loop must be as follows with the ugly spaces around equal sign in properties file which must be additionally removed: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%I in ("testing.properties") do set "%%I=%%J"`. No variable name (line) should start with `;` because of `for` ignores those lines. On no spaces around equal sign the __FOR__ loop would be: `for /F "usebackq delims= eol=" %%I in ("testing.properties") do set "%%I"`. See also [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the properies file really contain the spaces between the `=` ?

Something like this will read all the properies and display their values only:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%i in (testing.properties) do echo %%i
pause
```

where this will display the property name as well as the value:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (testing.properties) do echo Property: %%i Value: %%j
pause
```

if you really want to set the properties as variables (to use as readable variables).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (testing.properties) do (
    set property=%%i
    set value=%%j
    echo !property! !value!
)
pause
```

Comparing values and then setting them is another task on its own. Here you are giving an example, so give a real example and we can work from there. For instance. We can set the property name value as the vaiable name without manually typing it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (testing.properties) do (
    set %%i=%%j
    echo Property: %%i has Value: !%%i!
)
pause
```

or even add a something to the string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in (testing.properties) do (
    set local_%%i=%%j
    echo Property: %%i has value !local_%%i! set as Variable local_%%i
)
pause
```

Finally, giving your variables unique names will depend on some search criteria, you can probably use identifiers from your properties. For instance do a `findstr` on part of your property, or simply matching a numeric value or anything unique in a property.